# I've been building a theme and following some examples from others. One example I've found is the idea of loading

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been developing a Wordpress theme, and have been searching through some of the more skeletal frameworks for examples and education. I ran across one that uses content pages called from their "parent" theme page- i.e.- "content-page.php" being accessed via get_template_part('content') in the "page.php" page. I like the modular approach, but before implementing the practice, I'm wondering if this will affect loading times, or if this is best practice in general. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used that same technique when developing JointsWP. It seems to be a mainstay in most WP themes nowadays (including _s - the blank theme developed by Automattic) and I didn't notice any loading time issues when transitioning to the approach.

However, a caching plugin would easily resolve any issues you may have.